# Haskell Zip Parse Error

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use the zip function in Haskell to join two lists together. The lists **could be** defined and info gathered as follows:

```
 priority <- getLine    
 let priorityList = []
 priority : priorityList

 name<- getLine
 let nameList = []
 name : nameList
```

After gathering the info, the expected output would be priorityList = [1,2,3] & nameList = [test1, test2, test3]. However, this is unimportant for the purpose of the question, it can be assumed that the two lists are in the following format:

```
  priorityList = [1,2,3]
  nameList = [test1, test2, test3]
```

I need to combine the lists and print with the following function. However, i am getting the error 'parse error on input `zip''

```
printList :: IO ()
printList = do putStrLn "Printed Combined List"
               zip [nameList][priorityList]
```

Comment: Are you lying to us? Wherever you run the code in the upper half of the posting, iut was not Haskell.

Comment: Please copy+paste your *exact* code into the question. There are multiple reasons why the code that you say worked could not have compiled, much less run. This in turn gives us less confidence that any solution we identify to your second block of code applies to the actual block of code you tried to run on your computer.

Comment: Apologies, i should have excluded the information gathering section. That was irrelevant really. Using the assistance in the below answer i have been able to run the function correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
printList :: IO ()
printList = do putStrLn "Printed Combined List"
    zip [NameList][PriorityList]
```

There are many things wrong with this code.

The parse error you are seeing is because the do block is not properly aligned. The `zip` on the last line must line up with the `putStrLn` on the line before. So either

```
printList :: IO ()
printList = do putStrLn "Printed Combined List"
               zip [NameList][PriorityList]
```

or

```
printList :: IO ()
printList = do
    putStrLn "Printed Combined List"
    zip [NameList][PriorityList]
```

But that still won't work. `printList` is declared to be an IO action, which means the final line of the do block must be an IO action also... but `zip` produces a list. You may have meant this:

```
printList :: IO [(String, Int)]
printList = do
    putStrLn "Printed Combined List"
    return (zip [NameList][PriorityList])
```

but that will only print out the result when you run it directly from the ghci prompt. Better to print it out explicitly:

```
printList :: IO ()
printList = do
    putStrLn "Printed Combined List"
    print (zip [NameList][PriorityList])
```

But it still won't do what you want! Because `NameList` and `PriorityList` are, presumably, lists. That you want zipped together. But that's not what you're giving to `zip`: you're giving `zip` two new single element lists. You no doubt intended just to pass the lists directly.

```
printList :: IO ()
printList = do
    putStrLn "Printed Combined List"
    print (zip NameList PriorityList)
```

Oh, but it still won't work. Won't even compile. And why is that? Because variable names must start with lower case letters (or an underscore). And you've started both `NameList` and `PriorityList` with capital letters. Which is one reason why your first block of code so obviously could not have worked.

```
printList :: IO ()
printList = do
    putStrLn "Printed Combined List"
    print (zip nameList priorityList)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the above assistance, i have been able to construct a function (below) to achieve a successful ZIP (Excluding information gathering).

```
printList :: IO ()
printList = do
    let nameList = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
    let prioirtyList = [1, 2, 3]
    putStrLn "Printed Combined List"
    print (zip nameList prioirtyList)
```

My output is as follows:

```
*Main> printList
 Printed Combined List
 [("test1",1),("test2",2),("test3",3)]
```