# Haskell Ending Loop Return

Tags: haskell

I am trying to stop my program from stopping after the loop in a function ends. Let me first give some background - After a recent failed attempt at Haskell ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635012/haskell-zip-function-error-with-code/15635750?noredirect=1#15635750)) i have been working through a number of tutorials and have been able to successfully create myself lists containing both a name and priority (Below, working Code - Apologies if the copy/paste has miss-indented it).

```
module Main where

-- Function Main, gather details, then print
main :: IO ()
main = do info <- gatherInfo
      let names = info
      putStrLn . unlines . map printDetails $ names

-- Function to Get the Info
gatherInfo :: IO [(String, Int)]
gatherInfo = do putStr "Name: "
            name <- getLine
            if name == "quit"
              then return []
              else do priority <- getPri
                      let info = (name,priority)
                      otherInfo <- gatherInfo
                      return $ info : otherInfo

 -- Function to get Priority                          
 getPri :: IO Int
 getPri = do putStr "Priority: "
        input <- getLine
        let parsed = reads input
        if parsed == []
          then do putStrLn "Incorrect Entry, please enter again"
                  getPri
          else return $ fst $ parsed !! 0


 --Function to print each detail
 printDetails :: (String, Int) -> String
 printDetails (name, priorityScore) = "Name: " ++ name ++ "Priority: " ++ show priorityScore
```

This code will print the following output(incl user input):

```
 Patient Name: test1
 Patient Priority: 1

 Patient Name: test2
 Patient Priority: 2

 Patient Name: quit

 Patient name: test1 Priority: 1
 Patient name: test2 Priority: 2
```

As you can see, the list items are entered and then upon entering 'quit' the code prints the list contents.

The problem i have is that upon entering 'quit' and printing the list items, when i enter back into the program the items have gone.

What i am trying to achieve is running the gatherInfo function, then printing the list (in its entirety) and then going back to the gatherInfo function to add another item. For example, my output may be like:

```
 Patient Name: test1
 Patient Priority: 1

 Patient name: test1 Priority: 1

 Patient Name: test2
 Patient Priority: 2

 Patient name: test1 Priority: 1
 Patient name: test2 Priority: 2

 Patient Name: quit (Quit program, doesn't matter what happens now)
```

I have made several attempts at implementing this; for example, calling my printDetails function during each gatherInfo loop to print 'info', but with little success. How can i implement this into my design?

Comment: Can't you just call main on the last line of main to make the program run again?

Comment: Do you want the data to persist between invocations of the program?

Comment: @pat does this mean, the data remains between restarting program?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you actually want to quit the program, and then, when you restart it, you want all the data to still be there.  Is that really what you want, or do you simply want to go back into the question and answer loop to add more patients when you quit?

Comment: I require to go back into the question and answer loop to add more patients when i quit (after the list has printed)

Comment: @DiegoNolan adding main on the last line of main will simply print the list, then initiate main again (without the previous list components).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you do this:
Modify your gather info function so it takes info of only one patient.
Then create another function, let's call it main':

```
main' patients = do patient <- gatherInfo
                    if (fst patient == "quit") 
                       then return ()
                       else do 
                               let patients' = patient:patients   -- add patient to list of patients
                               putStrLn . unlines . map printDetails $ patients' -- print list of patients
                               main' patients'  -- continue
```

What are we doing here is remembering state of your program by passing parameter (this is how it is done in Haskell, as you have no states).
Now your main function would look like this:

```
main = main' []   -- start with empty list of patients
```

You may notice that I presumed your function gatherInfo will return patient with name "quit" when user inputs "quit", however you can do that some other way

Comment: You cannot add `patient` to the end of the list with `(:)`

Comment: This modification seems to be giving me a 'parse error on input `putStrLn' error. I will try and investigate more.

Comment: @ZeeeeeV Have you modified gatherInfo function to return (String, Int) instead of [(String, Int)]?

Comment: @Martinsos i have yes, i have also tried multiple ways of formatting incase this was the issue.

Comment: @ZeeeeeV Could you give some more info about the error, or post the code that you currently have? Do you understand the idea that I proposed? If you do then I believe you should be able to resolve the rest on your own. Also I didn't check my code above for syntax errors, it is more for demonstrative purpose. If you are copy - pasting it into your program then check for syntax errors and indentations

Comment: @ZeeeeeV I believe I know what was the problem, I added the "do" after "else" I believe it should work now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27013/discussion-between-zeeeeev-and-martinsos)